# Check internet connection availability using sql script/ query without using SQLCLR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am sending the mail through sp_send_dbmail stored procedure. Executing sp_send_dbmail SP from another SP. Before I execute sp_send_dbmail SP i want to check the internet connectivity. Is there any query to find the internet connectivity. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to check Internet connectivity? Internet connectivity is no indicator of whether or not sp_send_dbmail will work.

When I supported a SQL Server, the SQL Server box had Internet connectivity but that connection was not used to send emails. Instead, the SQL Server box forwarded all emails to our mail server which ultimately sent them.

If you check the Remarks section of the [article on sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx), you will see that the success of sending emails has to do with configuring mail services and not Internet connectivity.

Comment: When i execute sp_send_dbmail, if network cable is unplugged the mail goes to queue and its status will be 3(retrying). It will retry for maybe 1 minutes. If network is down it enter the failed state. Once it goes to failed state it wont retry. If network is up after 10 minutes it should send the mail. but here its not happening. Please give any other suggestion. Check the below link. Provided the solution using SQLCLR. But i want using SQL query. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900030/check-internet-connectivity-from-sql-query-script)

Comment: In mail setup, check the Database Mail Executable Minimum Lifetime (seconds) setting. The default is 6000 which is 10 minutes. You can adjust the setting with sysmail_configure_sp. As far as network connectivity though, I would set up a network monitor and have it inform you of the problem. Even if you detect it in SQL Server, it can't inform you because it is disconnected.

Comment: Thanks that really helps me a lot. In sysmail_configuration table AccountRetryDelay is static. But i want to implement RetryDelay logic for the first time retry time is 10 min, second time 20, third time 40 and so on. In c# there is method System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() it checks the internet connectivity. Is there any similar SP or query to check the connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `Exception handling` in the `Stored Proc` will get the following details.

**Error Message**

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

**Error Number - 53**

This is not an ideal way but the Error Number/Message can be checked to see if the request is able to reach destination. See the screen shot below...

[image]