# Check Internet Connectivity from sql query/script....?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can we check availability of internet from sql Script? I google'd a lot with no use.

Any suggestion regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You are best off making a SQL CLR function that uses the `WebClient` class to try and make a web request somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [SQL CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) UDF. Here is an example:

```cs
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlBoolean HasConnectivity(SqlString url)
{
    try
    {
        if (url.IsNull)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
        using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            //Make sure the Http Repsonse was HTTP 200 OK.
            return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. 100% sure this works, is ther any way to do it in SQL without using SQLCLR??

Comment: @sandeep Not to my knowledge. You could use `xp_cmdshell` and launch something like curl; however this is even more problematic and weird; but could be useful if you already have `xp_cmdshell` enabled and not SQL-CLR.

Comment: oh then its better i should go with SQLCLR

Answer (score 1):

Write a SQL Assembly which contains WebClient/TcpClient code to check internet,
then install the aseembly and call its methods in SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [ping some hosts using T-SQL procedure](http://5mins.wordpress.com/2009/08/20/pingscanner-using-t-sql-in-sql-server/).